# Speed penalty for converting between Tcl array and dict

Tags: optimization, tcl

I have a large Tcl application which relies *heavily* on arrays. To speed it up, I am contemplating rewriting it using dict instead of array. Due to its size, I would like to rewrite only the most calculation intensive part and convert between array and dict at the border of the two subsystems, in the way which is explained in http://wiki.tcl.tk/5042 in paragraph "Dictionaries and arrays".

Do I have to consider a serious speed penality from this conversion process, or are the internal structures implementing so similar, that the actual conversion can be considered fast?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both arrays and dicts use hash tables internally; their performance is pretty similar (identical asymptotic big-O behaviour, perhaps a bit different in terms of actual speed). However, if you are using *compact integer keys* (i.e., 0, 1, 2, …) you would be better off using a Tcl list, which is potentially considerably faster (they're C arrays under the covers).

Comment: I'd like to see compact integers for dicts optimized. That wouldn't discurage to do stuff like `dict get {jsonArr {0 foo 1 bar 2 baz} error 0} jsonArr 1` (and let's face it: nested `dict get` with `lindex` doesn't look great) - PS: Lua does that.

Comment: I would have expected this too, but if the performance really is similar, how then come the big speed in difference reported in the Link I gave, and how do we explain the information in the Tcl release notes (for 8.5), that dict would have better performance than Array?

Comment: For the records: Be careful, and read the entire report, the reported performance difference at this [site](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Dict+VS+Array+Speed) turned out to be due to uncomparable operations being used on arrays vs. dicts (`unset` w/ and w/o pattern matching).