# Should one use arrays and or dictionaries in TCL

Tags: arrays, dictionary, tcl

Since Tcl 8.5, we have both dictionaries, and arrays. Now, everybody knows of the advantages of the dictionaries.

Is there an advantage to an array, other than the environment array?

Has anyone found the arrays' advantage, assuming that one needs not use the TCL older than 8.5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The big semantic advantage of arrays is that you can trace elements of the array; they really are collections of *variables.* This also means that you can use elements with commands like `vwait`, and have Tk widgets use them to store their models, and so on. (All of those depend on traces to work.)

The big semantic advantage of dictionaries is that you can pass them from one context to another cheaply; they really are *values.* This makes using them as an argument to a procedure or returning it from a procedure both trivial and cheap.

Syntactically, arrays are nicer.

Comment: Thanks.
Performance wise? (memory foorptint, access read/write).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218193/speed-penalty-for-converting-between-tcl-array-and-dict

Answer (score 4):

You can trace an array variable, but you cannot trace a dictionary value.

Other than that, the syntax for fetching an array value is more terse.

References: [array](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm) [dict](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm)